# Implementation of a simple infinite scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

This is the navigation on my Wordpress blog.

[image: Load More Postis]

When a user click the "Load More Posts" button (which is not really a button, but an `h1` tag), an ajax script is fired off that loads more posts to the home page.

I want to change this behavious so that the posts are loaded automatically when a user scrolls down to the bottom of the page.

The function that triggers the ajax post event looks like this:

```
$(".home #more_posts").click(function(e) {
    $("#more_posts .loader").animate({opacity: 1},200);
    $.post('<?php bloginfo('siteurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
        action: 'and_action',
        off: offset+number,
        pagenumber: page_number,
        query_post: '&orderby=date&order=<?  echo $order_post ?>&category_name=<? echo $_POST['category'] ?>'
    } , (.....)
});
```

The reason I want to implement this change is to achieve an inifinite scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting an answer forced me into digging deeper and finding a solution.

This is what I did to achieve a simple infinite scoroll effect. I hope that this will be of help to some.

```
var now = new Date().getTime();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 400) {     
        if (new Date().getTime() - now > 1000) {
            loadNextPage();
            now = new Date().getTime();   
    } 

function loadNextPage() 
{
    (...)
    $(window).scrollTop(position - 500);
}
```

Lets break the code apart:

1. The part where you just change the event that triggers the `loadNextPage()` function is pretty straightforward - you go from "click" to "scroll".
2. Then there is a conditional fires the function when the browser scrollbar is 400(px) from the bottom of the document.
3. Now the part with the `new Date()` object. This condition makes sure that the `loadNextPage()` function is not triggered multiple times for each scroll-down. The condition says that there must be at least a second's interval between each trigger of `loadNextPage()`.
4. Finally, at the end of `loadNextPage()` function, we move the scrollbar up a bit so that the first condition inside the `.on("scoroll")` event is not continuously matched, but it requires a user to scroll down to fire `loadNextPage()` again.